# Python unittest coverage branch miss on context __exit__

Tags: python, unit-testing, contextmanager, coverage.py, python-coverage

I've had a number of times where I've done the following:

```
#    code
m.   with open(somefile, modes) as data_interface:
..      ...
n.   ...
```

And then when trying to provide test coverage using python's coverage module it complains about missing a branch on the from the line where the 'with' is (line 'm') to the line after the block (line n).

I have yet to figure out how to get coverage to recognize the branch is not an issue. I eventually just go back to using the open() call without the context manager; but I would really prefer to keep using it within a context manager.

Ideas?

Comment: I've never had problems getting code-coverage in my context managers... Where did you get coverage.py from?  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/coverage What version are you using?

Comment: This might be a known issue:  https://bitbucket.org/ned/coveragepy/issue/146/context-managers-confuse-branch-coverage

Comment: What version of python are you running?  [This bug](https://bitbucket.org/ned/coveragepy/issue/319/invalid-coverage-report-when-using-2-with) seems to indicate that python2.7 might not be affected while python2.6 is.

Comment: I have run into this bug in Py2 and Py3. in this case, I'm using latest Py 2.7 available on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: @mgilson that's exactly what I'm running into. Thanks.